# Invalid list index 2

Tags: coldfusion

I' am getting `Invalid list index 2` which means that in the `index 2` is not defined. How can check if `index 2` is defined in ColdFusion?

```
<cfif
    ListGetAt('/pages.cfm/about-us/' 1 , "/") eq 'news' AND 
    ListGetAt('/pages.cfm/about-us/', 2 , "/") eq 'press' AND 
    ListGetAt('/pages.cfm/about-us/', 3 , "/") eq '2016'AND 
    ListGetAt('/pages.cfm/about-us/', 4 , "/") neq ''>
    <cfoutput>It Works!</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Comment: You can use `getToken()` which returns an empty string if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

It is working now.

```
<cfif
    ListLen('/pages.cfm/about-us/', "/") neq '' AND
    ListGetAt('/pages.cfm/about-us/', 1 , "/") eq 'news' AND 
    ListLen('/pages.cfm/about-us/', "/") neq '' AND
    ListGetAt('/pages.cfm/about-us/', 2 , "/") eq 'press' AND 
    ListLen('/pages.cfm/about-us/', "/") neq '' AND
    ListGetAt('/pages.cfm/about-us/', 3 , "/") eq '2016'AND 
    ListLen('/pages.cfm/about-us/', "/") neq '' AND
    ListGetAt('/pages.cfm/about-us/', 4 , "/") neq ''>
    <cfoutput>It Works!</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Comment: It's be better to do `ListLen('/pages.cfm/about-us/', "/") gte 4` as your first if clause, you don't need to check it each time.

Comment: Also, `ListLen('/pages.cfm/about-us/', "/") neq ''` would always return true.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to verify the text starts with a particular pattern, ie "/news/press/2016/{moreChars}/", it would be simpler to use a regular expression:

```
<cfif REFindNoCase("^/news/press/2016/[^/]+/", theStringToSearch)>
    found
</cfif>
```